# Requests -- how to tell if you're getting a 404

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using the Requests library and accessing a website to gather data from it with the following code:

```
r = requests.get(url)
```

I want to add error testing for when an improper URL is entered and a 404 error is returned. If I intentionally enter an invalid URL, when I do this:

```
print r
```

I get this:

```
<Response [404]>
```

EDIT:

I want to know how to test for that. The object type is still the same. When I do `r.content` or `r.text`, I simply get the HTML of a custom 404 page.

Comment: Look at the documentation: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ The first page states to look at r.status_code

Answer (score 483, accepted):

Look at the [`r.status_code` attribute](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes):

```
if r.status_code == 404:
    # A 404 was issued.
```

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/status/404')
>>> r.status_code
404
```

If you want `requests` to raise an exception for error codes (4xx or 5xx), call `r.raise_for_status()`:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/status/404')
>>> r.raise_for_status()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "requests/models.py", line 664, in raise_for_status
    raise http_error
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: NOT FOUND
>>> r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/status/200')
>>> r.raise_for_status()
>>> # no exception raised.
```

You can also test the response object in a boolean context; if the status code is not an error code (4xx or 5xx), it is considered ‘true’:

```
if r:
    # successful response
```

If you want to be more explicit, use `if r.ok:`.

Comment: Well damn that's annoying. I wish there was a way to get requests.get to raise for any reason except a 2XX without having to make extra calls.

Comment: @AsfandQazi: why would you want to raise an exception for a 1xx or 3xx status code? Those are not error conditions.

Comment: 1xx and 3xx should (and are) handled transparently by the library. I was talking specifically about 4xx errors. Of course sometimes you may want to read a 4xx response so we shouldn't impose it on everyone, but I wish there was a flag you could pass to `.get()` instead of calling a function afterwards.

Comment: @AsfandQazi: it's trivial to write your own wrapper function if that's important to you.

Comment: It just seems a bit untidy, that's all

Answer (score 7):

If your request is made inside another function, but you want to catch the error in a higher level, it is good to know that you can also get the status code directly from the exception. In my case I could not access the response since the HTTPError was raised before my function was able to pass on the response. I ended up doing the following:

```
try:
     r = function_calling_request(the_request)
except HTTPError as e:
     if e.response.status_code == 404:
          return do_stuff_if_not_found()
```