# Requests — how to tell if you're getting a success message?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, httprequest, http-response-codes

My question is closely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258728/requests-how-to-tell-if-youre-getting-a-404).

I'm using the Requests library to hit an HTTP endpoint.
I want to check if the response is a success.

I am currently doing this:

```
r = requests.get(url)
if 200 <= response.status_code <= 299:
    # Do something here!
```

Instead of doing that ugly check for values between 200 and 299, is there a shorthand I can use?

Answer (score 93):

[The response has an `ok` property](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.ok). Use that:

```
if response.ok:
    ...
```

The implementation is just a try/except around [`Response.raise_for_status`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/8149e9fe54c36951290f198e90d83c8a0498289c/requests/models.py#L936-L940), which is itself checks the status code.

```
@property
def ok(self):
    """Returns True if :attr:`status_code` is less than 400, False if not.

    This attribute checks if the status code of the response is between
    400 and 600 to see if there was a client error or a server error. If
    the status code is between 200 and 400, this will return True. This
    is **not** a check to see if the response code is ``200 OK``.
    """
    try:
        self.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Note that this counts the 3xx redirection range as okay, unlike the code in the question.

Comment: I don't think you'll usually see a 300-range status anyway, since `requests` is going to follow the redirect. You'll get the status of the URL you were redirected to.

Comment: It won't follow redirects if you pass `allow_redirects=False`

Comment: I think also the problem with this might be 1xx responses, which won't raise for status and aren't in the range of code in the question either.

Answer (score 15):

I am a Python newbie but I think the easiest way is:

```
if response.ok:
    # whatever
```

Answer (score 11):

The *pythonic* way to check for requests success would be to optionally raise an exception with

```
try:
    resp = requests.get(url)
    resp.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    print(err)
```

EAFP: It’s Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission: You should just do what you expect to work and if an exception might be thrown from the operation then catch it and deal with that fact.

Answer (score -3):

You could also do:

```
r = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code // 100 == 2:
    # Do something here!
```