# How to check if a string contains one substring variant in Python?

Tags: python, string, substring

How do I check if a string contains one substring variant like "all 3 digits numbers starting with 4 or 5"?

In my specific case, I want to check if an HTTP response header contains a 4xx or 5xx code.

Regex seems seems like overkill.

Comment: `s[0] in '45' and s[1:3].isdigit()` maybe? But at that point the regex is probably more readable `r'[45]\d\d'`

Comment: I am using requests library. The response text doesn't start with the code, so I can't check s[0].

Comment: is the response [`r.status_code`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) available to you?

Comment: @davedwards: it seems promising. I will give it a try. But the question still stands.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258728/requests-how-to-tell-if-youre-getting-a-404

Comment: @J.Doe in that case, `400 <= r.status_code <= 599`

Comment: @davedwards: actually, I now have read more carefully the link you sent and it says I can raise an exception if a bad request is made. But in my case, I am looking for bad requests (it's a link checker script), so treating it as an exception doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: @AnthonySottile: very elegant, but s3n0's link nailed it. In requests, I can check r.ok. Thanks guys!