# How get status code if an error occurred python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to get response status code if an error occurred

```py
try:
    r = requests.post('site.com')
except (requests.RequestException) as e:
    print(r.status_code)
```

i can't do that

I also know about

```py
r.raise_for_status()
```

But Exception raised before request so i can't do that

Comment: If an exception was raised before/during the request then there is no response status code because there is no response.

Comment: you should look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258728/requests-how-to-tell-if-youre-getting-a-404) it may help you to understand how to get the status code of a request

Comment: @DeepSpace what about "400 Bad Request"?

Comment: if you get an exception maybe post the exception trace. exceptions indicate something in the code went wrong. Getting a bad response 400 would still be a valid response obejct so shouldnt cause an exception

Comment: @Chris Doyle i'm trying to handle all RequestException like MissingSchema, ConnectionError, ConnectTimeout e.t.c. And i want to return correct status code

Comment: ok so just think about what you said, lets use connection error / connection timeout. How can you expect to get an http response code if you never succesfully made a request in the first place. the response code is set by the server when it returns an http response. if you have a connection error or time out than like deepspace said in the case of that exception there would be no status code

Comment: @Chris Doyle. Ok i get it. thank you, so if i want to log it i shouldn't log status code?

Comment: yeah if something went wrong when calling `requests.post(` then it means a request was never sent to there will be no response so no status code