# If condition on error message after response.read

Tags: python, urllib2

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/Hi")
html = response.read()
```

Is it possible that when the above code is run while the Hi directory has been removed (or the server is not available), instead of crashing, an action like below is done?

```
if html==404:
    print("No response")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `requests` module
simply after getting the request, check the status code

```py
    import requests
    r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/status/404')
    print(r.status_code) # the output is the int: 404
```

if everything is **ok**

```
if r.ok:
    # cool stuff :)
```

if page **not** found:

```
if r.status_code == 404:
    # so sad :(
```

Read more:
https://realpython.com/python-requests/

[Requests -- how to tell if you're getting a 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258728/requests-how-to-tell-if-youre-getting-a-404)