# How to send slack app message with incoming webhook from an input?

Tags: python, slack-api

Trying to send messages from python input script to slack app incoming webhook. It doesn't give an error but just accept and doesn't post

```
print()
name = input("What is your name? ")


def send_slack_message(message: str):

    import requests

    payload = '{"text": "%s"}' % name
    response = requests.post(
        'https://hooks.slack.com/services/*****************',
        data=payload
    )
    print(response.text)


def main(message_text: str):

    send_slack_message(message=message_text)
```

Comment: what is the `response.status_code`? or likely better `response.raise_for_status()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Requests -- how to tell if you're getting a 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258728/requests-how-to-tell-if-youre-getting-a-404)