# snowflake SQL page not found url field

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have got a table with an URL column. A small number of these URL records are outdated and will send you to a page not found site of the website. The URL itself doesn't update despite the "Page not found" error. Is there a way for me to filter out these URLs in an sql query?

Answer (score 0):

One way, which comes to my mind, is using Snowpark and a python procedure here.

Basically you are using Python to

- Loop over all records
- Opening each url and checking status: [Requests -- how to tell if you're getting a 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258728/requests-how-to-tell-if-youre-getting-a-404)
- Updating records accordingly