# Use Databricks (Azure) to find out if website url response is 404, 500 or 200

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

Is it possible to leverage Databricks to monitor several in-house applications by calling the URL (for example https://myapp.company.com/) and see if it returns a 404, 500 or 200 response code back?
Preferred language is Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Requests -- how to tell if you're getting a 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258728/requests-how-to-tell-if-youre-getting-a-404)

Comment: Any approach you tried?If yes what is the blockers you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Use the requests library (pre-installed on Databricks) to check the URL status:

```
import requests

x = requests.get('https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.htm')

print(x.status_code)
```